# How to create and run a macro that runs on current visual selection?

Tags: vim, macros, selection

I'd like to create a macro so that if I select a piece of text (either by a keyboard or a mouse) and invoke this macro, it adds `[b]` and `[/b]` around the text (for example). I'm familiar with recording macros using `q` and running them with `@`, but I couldn't figure out how to connect a macro with current visual selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are no different from what you would type to achieve your goal. When working with a visual selection, you'd typically use motions like `` `< `` and `` `> `` to go to the begin and end of the selection, and insert the tags with `i` and `a`; `gv` allows to you re-select the previous selection.

For your particular example, it may be worthwhile to look into the [surround.vim - Delete/change/add parentheses/quotes/XML-tags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin; maybe it already does what you want.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit ont his please? I have a similar issue, I want to replace commas with spaces inside the visual selection. The macro I defined is `let @c=':''<,''>s/,/ /g^M^['` But when I run it I get the error `E492: Not an editor command: '<,'>'<,'>s/,/ /g`.  So it seems that I should not add the visual range to the command. But when I change the macro to `let @c=':s/,/ /g^M^['` The substitute command is applied to the entire line.

Comment: Found the answer to my issue at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/replace-in-visual-selection the solution is to add `%V` to the substitute command. My macro needs to be `let @c=':s/\%V,/ /g^M^['`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @Bram: Yes, for Ex commands this is different. I personally would not assign this to a register (and call it a macro), but instead define a custom `:command` for it. Macros typically are sequences of normal-mode commands (maybe with one Ex command mixed in), not pure command-lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is the [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) plugin. It has a special "visual placeholder" mechanism.

> Snippets can contain a special placeholder called ${VISUAL}. The ${VISUAL}
>   variable is expanded with the text selected just prior to expanding the
>   snippet.

So you can define a snippet that surrounds visual selection with some particular tag:

```
snippet b "surrond with [b] tag"
[b]${1:${VISUAL}}[/b]
endsnippet
```

or you can make a generic snippet which surrounds visual selection with any tag:

```
snippet tag "surround with a tag"
[${1}]${2:${VISUAL}}[/$1]
endsnippet
```

or you can go nuts and utilize the power of Python interpolation to do whatever pre-processing you want with visually selected text inside the snippet.